# Экспорт в Файл Write

Tags: pascal

В Pascal как при помощи процедуры Write записывать данные в файл?

Comment: [WRITE](http://delphibasics.ru/Write.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень просто:
writeln(f,s), где f - переменная файла, а s - строка, которую ты записываешь

Comment: f - не переменная файла, а хэндл, указывающий на открытый файл, не обязательно текстовый =)

Answer (score 0):

[Запись в файл средствами Pascal](http://pascal.guti.ru/files.html)

Answer (score 0):

После того, как ты открыл файл, пишишь writeln(f, vars) где f файлового типа, а vars - переменные.

Еще в Delphi можно переоткрыть стандартный поток ввода-вывода
Нпр:
  rewrite(output, '...');
После этого все, что ты выводишь, будет выводиться в открытый файл, т.е. надо будет пользоваться только обычным writeln